# Como persistir uma informação do atributo tipo enum mas salvar ele em String no banco de dados?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa-2.0, spring-jpa

Atributo que estou tentando passar para String ->

```
@Column(name = "tb_prioridade_tarefa")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private PrioridadeEnum prioridade;
```

Como podem ver, tentei utilizar a anotação @Enumerated para fazer a persistência em tipo String, já havia usado ela antes e deu certo, porém nesse caso, não consegui.

Esse é o seguinte erro no teste que me apresenta ->
"message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement"

Classe enum ->

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

public enum PrioridadeEnum

```
ALTA, MEDIA, BAIXA;

private String prioridade;
```

Erro no console -> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "tb_prioridade_tarefa" is of type integer but expression is of type character varying
Dica: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você que está criando a tabela ou usando ddl-auto? Porque parece que o problema é o campo estar com integer.

Eu tenho um código aqui que apenas está como se fosse assim e funciona:

```java
package pacote;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "exemplo")
public class Exemplo {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private PrioridadeEnum prioridade;
}
```

```java
package pacote;
public enum PrioridadeEnum {
    ALTA, MEDIA, BAIXA;
}
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE exemplo
(
    id VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    prioridade VARCHAR(255),
    CONSTRAINT exemplo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: Fala Marcos, Bom dia meu amigo. Muito obrigado pela solução ai, deu certo demais por aqui. Obrigado msm